# Change view controller maintaining navigation hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

Using the diagram below as a reference, I'm trying to go from controller A to controller B-2 when the users pushes a button.

I'm fairly new to iOS so I'm having some problems.
If I push the B-2 controller or create a segue the hierarchy is not respected and the B-2 controller is not inside the navigation controller (B).

I want the user to still have the navigation funcionalities and to still be able to go back to controller B-1 using the back button.

Controllers A & B are both under the same Tab controller  (Z)

How can I achieve this?

[image: Diagram]

Comment: try adding navigation controller to 'A' and then push it

Comment: But then if you go back you return to A, not to B-1
I'd like to keep the hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found this solution:

From controller A I get the parent (Z), set the active controller to the second child (B) and get his child (B-1).

Once I have B-1 I can call perform segue and it works pretty good.
The hierarchy is correct and it's exactly the behaviour I wanted

The code is this

```
if let tab = self.parentViewController as? UITabBarController{
            tab.selectedIndex = 1
            if let one = tab.childViewControllers[1] as? UINavigationController{
                if let two = one.childViewControllers[0] as? MatchTableViewController{
                    two.performSegueWithIdentifier("open_chat_view", sender: matchModel)
                }
            }
        }
```